Visual studio 2022 add existing file to project "The operation could not be completed"
If I try to add (right click on folder Add->Existing item...) existing file to the project I receive an error:
The operation could not be completed. Unspecified error
I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit) - Current Version 17.11.5
What I've tried so far:

I deleted the .vs folder.

I deleted the obj folder.

I cleaned and built solution

I update Visual Studio to the newest version

I tried adding by mouse (Add->Existing item...) and keys combination (Shift + Alt + A)



I would like to know what type of file you added and whether you have tried to create a new project to see if you can reproduce the problem. In addition, I suggest you try to reinstall VS to see if it works. If it still doesn't work, I suggest you collect relevant logs:
Enter the Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022:
devenv /log "\Path_to_store_logs\xxx.xml"
After opening VS here, please reproduce this issue, finally close VS and upload the generated log.

After launching visual studio from the Developer Command Promp, adding existing files started working. Turn on sarcasm. I love it when magic happens. Turn off sarcasm.Thanks for your help
